# Epipolar lines with known rotation and translation

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I want to calculate the epipolar lines for the interest points between two images.  I am working on a fountain dataset, so I have the rotation and translation matrix, as well as the camera matrix.  I currently use Matlab in order to be fast, but the version I have is quite old(2009).

I am calculating the essential matrix through E=t*R and then the epipolar line with l=E*P, where P is the interest point/set of interest points.  Then I get a vector with three lines which I guess are the line parameters of ax+by+c=0.  The epipolar line drawn on the right image is totally wrong, far away from the point on the left image.  Any idea???

Edit: Used dataset --> fountain benchmark, images 0000 and 0001 http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~strecha/multiview/denseMVS.html

Output: Essential matrix e.g. for point P1=[433.36;861.15;1]

E =

```
0.761857065048902  1.969487475012598 40.418915885686594

-0.927781947178923 0.698934833377211 33.173562943087106

-45.044061511303227 -26.573128396975097 1.000000000000000
```

It has two complex eigenvalues that are conjugated.

Epipolar line:1.0e+004 *

0.206660143270238
   0.023299771007641
  -4.240274401559348

Comment: The issues you're having could result from any number of things: not understanding the concepts, using the wrong operations in Matlab, poor quality images, etc.  Providing a sample of what you're working on (code, images, output, etc..) would certainly help.  If you're question isn't resolved by the time I get off work, I will try to provide a worked out solution.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem. I post it here in case somebody else is interested.

To calculate correctly the relative rotation and translation matrices, the Roto-Translation matrix has to be used. This matrix is a 4x4 matrix for every image. The upper left part is the rotation (wrt the world coordinate system), the 4th sub-column is the translation vector (wrt to the world coordinate system) and the last row is [0 0 0 1]. So, if we have 2 such matrices for 2 images, the final roto-translation matrix is Qright-->left=inv(Qright)*Qleft. From this matrix, we extract the relative translation (t) and rotation(R) (4th sub column and upper left matrix respectively). Then, we create the skew symmetric matrix T for translation. The epipolar matrix is E=R*T. But this isn't enough. In order to calculate correctly the epipolar lines, the Fundamental matrix F has to be found. For a given dataset such the one I used, camera matrices K are given so this is easy: F=inv(Kright')*E*inv(Kleft), where (') is the transposed and inv is the inverted matrix. Then, the epipolar lines of the right image are calculated lines=F*P, where P is the point in homogeneous coordinates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of documents that can found online that explain epipolar geometry and how to find epipolar lines in stereo images.  Here is [one](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/EpipolarGeonetry.pdf).  It walks you through different concepts decently.  The trick to this topic, I found, is keeping track of the variables which are ultimately the result of matrix transformations and **implied** (professor shortcuts) algabraic operations.

**My recommendation would be looking at page 12 of the link I've provided and applying it your scenario.**  Without any data to go off of other than the description you've provided, it's impossible to work out the problem.

Good luck.

Note: sorry to hear your Matlab version is old. I know that 2013 has built in functions for this stuff, but I'm not sure if 2009 does because MathWorks requries an account to read older documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I have already checked millions of epipolar geometry manuals. The problem is that I am doing something wrong during implementation. You can check the edit above.

Comment: I know that in MATLAB 2013 you can compute with ready function all this stuff, bit in any case I should try that way as well.

Comment: Ok, I am still looking at this problem. I guess it is a problem of the rotation and the translation matrices I provided in E=t*R. The dataset I use includes some .camera files that give information about R and t wrt the world reference system. Now, I have to find the relative translation and rotation between the cameras. I did it like the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283501/how-to-calculate-extrinsic-parameters-of-one-camera-relative-to-the-second-camer but still I don't have good results. Any recommentation?